# Running PhantomJS with PHP server side

Tags: php, phantomjs, exec

I'm trying to run PhantomJS using PHP on a Linux web server. This will eventually run as a cron job but for now I'm running it through a PHP script that I am uploading via FTP to the server.

PHP script:

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/accountname/public_html/myscript.js';
$result = exec($cmd);
var_dump($result);
```

*(Note that I have changed the account name in the path above to "accountname" for privacy but this is correct in my real script - and is copied from a myriad of other PHP scripts which all work perfectly.)*

myscript.js content:

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

The resulting output is:

```
string(0) ""
```

I have tried a number of examples from the PhantomJS website an I never get any output - either on the screen, in the console or for the examples that create screenshots the PNG files never appear in the right place - even though I am specifying exact paths.

I did try returning the PhantomJS version and this returned the correct version:

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --version';
$result = exec($cmd);
var_dump($result);
```

Returned:

```
string(5) "1.9.2"
```

I know that "exec" is not a safe way of running things in PHP - but I'm just trying to test that PhantomJS works to get started, and then we'll adjust everything to work safely.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear. Did you run myscript.js directly and did it output the correct string? What OS/platform are you on?

Comment: Well, myscript.js has a PhantomJS specific call "phantom.exit();" but if I take that out and call the JS file directly, then yes it works.

If I run the PHP containing the code shown in my original example, and run that script using a cron job, then it works fine. It's just executing it from within a browser that causes the problem.

I have got around the problem by running a regular cron job, and updating the PHP to reference a MySQL table that is acting as a queue to pass it the JS file, and schedule when this task is required.

It's a managed hosted server running CENTOS 5.11

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
$cmd = 'unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;';
$cmd.= ' /usr/local/bin/phantomjs'; //where is isntalled phantomjs
$cmd.= ' /var/www/rasterize.js'; //where is your script
exec($cmd.' 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

This script was tested on Ubuntu 12.04 with php 5.4.